# hadoop/HDFS: Is it possible to write from several processes to the same file?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

f.e. create file 20bytes.
1st process will write from 0 to 4
2nd from 5 to 9
etc

I need this to parallel creating a big files using my MapReduce.

Thanks.

P.S. Maybe it is not implemented yet, but it is possible in general - point me where I should dig please.

Comment: why do you want to write to the **same** file in parallel? And how is that related to mapreduce?

Comment: I want to speed up this process. I can do parallel data calculation. Now I should find a way to write ready data to file. Better in parallel instead of queuing.

Comment: You can't speed this up, at least not by writing to a single file.

Comment: Could you explain your point? Web downloaders like Free Download Manager, uTorrent, Transmission, etc are using this feature. AFAIK.

Comment: How do you know that they are downloading to a single file instead of n-parallel files and then just merge?

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to explain what you plan to do with this file after you have created it.

If you need to get it out of HDFS to then use it then you can let Hadoop M/R create separate files and then use a command like `hadoop fs -cat /path/to/output/part* > localfile` to combine the parts to a single file and save off to the local file system.

Otherwise, there is no way you can have multiple writers open to the same file - reading and writing to HDFS is stream based, and while you can have multiple readers open (possibly reading different blocks), multiple writing is not possible.

Web downloaders request parts of the file using the [Range HTTP header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) in multiple threads, and then either using tmp files before merging the parts together later (as Thomas Jungblut suggests), or they might be able to make use of Random IO, buffering the downloaded parts in memory before writing them off to the output file in the correct location. You unfortunately don't have the ability to perform random output with Hadoop HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is no. The way you accomplish this is write your multiple 'preliminary' files to hadoop and then M/R them into a single consolidated file.  Basically, use hadoop, don't reinvent the wheel.